# Parameterize the target framework of a Visual Studio template project

Tags: visual-studio, templates

When exporting a project as a template in Visual Studio I noticed that the "TargetFramework" property of the .csproj file in the .zip archive is not parameterized but hardcoded as the framework version used to create the project from which the template.

My question is - is it possible to create a project template but make it so that the "TargetFramework" property is changed depending on the user's settings/machine/etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to honor the framework selected by the user on the *new project* dialog, you can use the *targetframeworkversion* parameter, so the csproj template would be `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v$targetframeworkversion$</TargetFrameworkVersion>`.

If you don't want the user to select the target framework version, you should disable the corresponding combo box on the *new project* dialog, I don't know if there is a way to achieve this. Then, [on the project wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2019), you have to either set the value of the parameter *targetframeworkversion* or add your own parameter.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and the New Project dialog no longer has a drop down list of target frameworks to populate the $targetframeworkversion$ variable. It is defaulting to 4.5. Do you know how I set the variable?